# Aurelia CLI PWA with Webpack and Workbox

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, aurelia

Last night I attempted to create a PWA using the latest aurelia-cli (version 0.32.0). I created a custom setup with `au new` that uses Webpack and TypeScript.

After that I followed the [Workbox with Webpack instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/get-started/webpack) from Google.

- npm install workbox-cli --saveDev
- npm install workbox-webpack-plugin --saveDev

  - service worker is running
  - offline fails doesn't find webpack-dev-server.js (not in dist), app.xxx.bundle.js and vendor.asdf.js are not in the generated sw.js even though in dist folder
  - au run --watch infinite compiling loop

My code is in [my Github branch](https://github.com/aligneddev/hn-pwa-aurelia/tree/restartNewCli), but by following these steps you should be able to reproduce it.

Am I placing the WorkboxPlugin in the `webpack.config.js` in the wrong place?

How do I get the offline with the service worker working?