# Adding service workers in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, service-worker, aurelia

To make my aurelia app a proper PWA, that I have created using aurelia cli, I need to register a service worker.

There is already a similar unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023333/aurelia-cli-pwa-with-webpack-and-workbox) or few [discussions](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/aurelia-hn-progressive-web-app-pwa-example/142/2) and [forum posts](https://www.bartvanuden.com/2017/12/14/from-spa-to-pwa-with-asp-net-core-2-0-and-aurelia/) on the web available regarding the subject matter but I couldn't find anything concrete to help me get started.

I am thinking of three possible ways to handle this

option[1] - use index.html page and register a service worer inside a script tag outside the scope of aurelia app.

```
// service worker in index.html file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
     ... my service worker code here ...
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

option[2] - inside aurelia main.js/main.ts

```
// inside aurelia main.js/main.ts file

export function configure(aurelia) {
  ... rest of the conf ...
  registerServiceWorker();
  return aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app')));
}
```

option [3] -  app.js file

```
// inside app.js file constructor

export class App {

  constructor() {

    this.registerServiceWorker();
  }
```

What would be the proper/right way to handle this task? As I am using webpack, would it need more configuration to make the service worker play nice with webpack and aurelia?

If using WorkBox is the only way forward, I can live with that too but to keep things simple I would prefer to use vanilla service workers directly in aurelia.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it to work.

1- insatll workbox plugin

```
yarn add workbox-webpack-plugin
```

2- configure webpack

```
//webpack.config.js
// add plugin somewhere in the top section 

const  workboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

//inside plugins section 
 plugins: [
   // somewhere in the bottom is OK 
   new workboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      swDest: 'sw.js', // name of your service worker file
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true
    }),
```

3- put your sw.js file in static dir. It will be moved to the dist folder on build.

4- if it is a complete PWA, add manifest.json file too in the static dir. you can get a sample manifest.json file from [google developr site](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/).

5- add service worker init script into the index file

```
 // index.html or index.ejs file
 <script>

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
      .then(function(registration) { return registration.update(); })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

</script>
```

run and hopefully you should get the serveiceworker installed and running.

P.S. is this the proper way to do it? I have no idea, but for now it is working for me.